# MVC 4 OAuth - How to prevent unauthorized users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Folks,

I just moved to VS 2012 from VS 2010. I am still figuring out the new SimpleMembershipProvider and OAuth provider.

After creating a default "Internet" project, I enabled Google client. It seems now I can login using either local username/password or Google authentication.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand the following:

1. I would like only authorized users to login. It seems any Google user is able to login at the moment. How do I prevent this?
2. I would like to set it up such that although anyone can request for "registration," only admins will decide who is allowed to access the system. How can I achieve this?
3. Is there a way to completely get rid of local username/password and just use Google authentication instead?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Using OAuth Providers with MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)

There is a tutorial witch shows how you authenticate with Facebook account (with Google will be same), but authorization process need some "wizard". And after success registatrion wizard user is allow to access website. Of course you will have to change above wizard to your needs.